# Why does my <a> tag play the mp3 in new tab instead of downloading, even though I've included download="filename.mp3"?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-storage, anchor, next.js13

I'm building a webpage using Next.js (version 13) for the frontend and Firebase for the backend. I'm trying to build an `<a>` tag on the frontend that, when clicked, will download an mp3 file. Right now, when clicked, it opens in a new tab and plays the mp3 file even though I have added `download='filename.mp3'` to the anchor tag. How can I get it to download instead?

My suspicion is that it has something to do with how Firebase storage builds the download URL, but I don't know what to look for or how to test it.

app/components/SongLinks.tsx

```
'use client'
import { BsDownload } from 'react-icons/bs'


export default function SongLinks({ downloadURL }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {downloadURL ? (
        <a href={downloadURL} download='filename.mp3'>
        </a>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

There is an app/[songSlug]/page.tsx file that is calling this SongLinks.tsx component and passing the `downloadURL` prop to the SongLinks.tsx component after first getting the song data from Firebase and then calling `getAudioDownloadUrl()` from the /lib/firebase.ts file. That function looks like this:

/lib/firebase.ts

```
export function getAudioDownloadUrl({
  audioFilePath,
}: {
  audioFilePath: string
}): Promise<string> {
  return getDownloadURL(ref(storage, audioFilePath))
}
```

So basically, in testing this particular song, app/[songSlug]/page.tsx passes `downloadURL` to SongLinks.tsx with a value of:

"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/the-second-messenger-website.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fmrpm0_Saving%20Aleah.mp3?alt=media&token=6d473b20-5d1e-4415-ae27-fd41b2cb30bc"

This works well enough to play the mp3 file in a new browser tab, so I'm fairly certain I'm referencing the Firebase storage bucket correctly. What I'm not sure of is if this is causing some cross-origin problem that is preventing the mp3 from being downloadable. IDK...

I have also tried writing the SongLinks component like this:

app/components/SongLinks.tsx

```
'use client'
import { BsDownload } from 'react-icons/bs'

export default function SongLinks({ downloadURL }) {

  const downloadFileAtURL = (url) => {
    const aTag = document.createElement('a')
    aTag.href = url
    aTag.setAttribute('download', 'Saving Aleah.mp3')
    document.body.appendChild(aTag)
    aTag.click()
    aTag.remove()
  }

  return (
    <div id={selectors['song_links']}>
      {downloadURL ? (
        <a>
          <BsDownload
            onClick={() => {
              downloadFileAtURL(downloadURL)
            }}
          />
        </a>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But this version of the component still opens the mp3 file in a new tab instead of downloading it. What am I missing? Please help. Thank you!